# How check values in foreach loop which have value 1

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch a field(Status) from a table OrderItem which have multiple rows with a same orderID . The field status is a logical value mean 1 for pending and 2 for picked i want to show  any of row status is 1 then it set to pending and if all are 2 it set to picked

```
            $stmt_chk = "SELECT order_item_status FROM order_item WHERE order_id='$orderId'";
            $ex_stmt = $db->query($stmt_chk);
                       //$resu_stmt = $ex_stmt->fetch_array();
            while($resu_stmt = $ex_stmt->fetch_row()) {
                           $stmtstatus  = $resu_stmt;
                           $it_status = $stmtstatus;
                           foreach($it_status as $status) {
                            echo $status."<br>";
                            if($status == 2 ) {
                                $item_orstatu = 2;
                                //echo $item_orstatu;
                            }
                            else {
                                $item_orstatu = 1;
                                //echo 'Picked';
                            }
                            //echo $status."<br>";
                           }
                           //echo $it_status[0];
                           //print_r($it_status);
                           //echo $it_status['order_item_status'];
                       }
            if($item_orstatu == 1) {
            echo '<b style=color:#f70606>'.'Pending'."</b>";
            }
            else {
                echo '<b style=color:#63b10d>'.'Picked'."</b>";
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN()` in the query.

```
SELECT IF(MIN(status) = 1, 'pending', 'picked') AS order_status
FROM order_item
WHERE order_id = '$order_id'
```